# How to update a news feed in an iPhone app without updating app?

Tags: ios, feed

I will develop a small iPhone application for a festival.

I want to create a news page with the latest news about the festival.

How can I simply add news in my app without using Xcode for updating the app ?

RSS feed ? Are they other methods ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a rest service backend or add the data to a file that you load via network from Rest, SOAP or even googledrive/dropbox...

[Dropbox Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325616/downloading-a-file-from-dropbox-for-documents-directory-deletes-all-my-files)

[Google Drive Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450999/ios-how-to-download-google-docs-files-using-ios-google-drive-sdk-api)